# WDT710PAYM4 Whirlpool Dishwasher part needed

Tags: repair, dishwasher

I am looking to replace a part on my dishwasher. It's called the cover latch in the manual. I can't seem to find the part number listed anywhere.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to happen upon the whirlpoolparts.com website and entered what I thought was the correct name of "cover latch". It ended up being the whole assembly called "[Whirlpool Dishwasher Detergent Dispenser WPW10195175](https://www.whirlpoolparts.com/PartDetail/Detergent-Dispenser/WPW10195175/1872068?modelNumber=WDT710PAYM4)".

Answer (score 0):

A quick google and ebay search showed your part available there for about $125 (Canadian). I doubt, you will be able to find that tiny plastic piece separate as per the link you listed and the schematics. I would also check local repair shops, they often have pieces and parts (new and used)for sale.

Comment: EBay prices are so variable that I would seek a second opinion.  I mean that if the going rate through authorized parts channels is $100, eBay will have it for $40, $80, $300 or $600. A lot of ebay listings are bottom feeders who capitalize on people not knowing what normal pricing should be.

Comment: I agree 100% with you @Harper, which is why I also included the part about checking local shops and other places.

Answer (score 0):

When you see a number on a part, that is typically a drawing number, not a part number. Part numbers are gotten from the parts manual.

Typically, online websites provide the part manual functionality, either by asking you/searching for which part, or showing you pages from the parts manual.